# AWS MediaConvert: Unable to write to output file [s3://undefined/test.mp4]: [Failed to write data: Access Denied]

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

I'm trying to create an AWS Elemental MediaConvert Job via node.js, and I've run across the following issue:

> Error message: Unable to write to output file [s3://undefined/test.mp4]: [Failed to write data: Access Denied]

[AWS MediaConvert Job summary Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zVzn.png)

The code itself successfully creates and starts the job, but the job fails because somewhere along the way the destination s3 bucket in outputGroupSettings was set to 'undefined'.

The issue occurs in createMediaJobTemplate() in the try block.

```js
const {MediaConvertClient} = require('@aws-sdk/client-mediaconvert');
const {CreateJobCommand, CreateJobTemplateCommand} = require('@aws-sdk/client-mediaconvert');
// aws
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
const mediaConvert = new AWS.MediaConvert({apiVersion: '2017-08-29'});

require('dotenv').config();
const queue_arn = 'arn:aws:mediaconvert:us-east-1:number:queues/queue name'; // not my actual arn
const role_arn = 'arn:aws:iam::number:role/service-role/MediaConvert_Default_Role'; // not my actual arn
const job_template_name = 'Media Transcoding Job Template';

async function getEmcClient() {
  const endpoint = await getEndpoint();
  const emc_client = new MediaConvertClient({endpoint: endpoint});
  return emc_client;
}

async function createMediaJobTemplate(template_name, output_bucket) {
  const client = await getEmcClient();
  const destination = `s3://${output_bucket}/`;
  const params = {
    'Category': '',
    'Description': '',
    'Name': template_name,
    'Queue': queue_arn,
    'Settings': {
      'AdAvailOffset': 0,
      'TimecodeConfig': {
        'Source': 'EMBEDDED',
      },
      'Inputs': [
        {
          'AudioSelectors': {
            'Audio Selector 1': {
              'Offset': 0,
              'DefaultSelection': 'NOT_DEFAULT',
              'ProgramSelection': 1,
              'SelectorType': 'TRACK',
              'Tracks': [1],
            },
          },
          'FilterEnable': 'AUTO',
          'PsiControl': 'USE_PSI',
          'FilterStrength': 0,
          'DeblockFilter': 'DISABLED',
          'DenoiseFilter': 'DISABLED',
          'TimecodeSource': 'EMBEDDED',
          'VideoSelector': {
            'ColorSpace': 'FOLLOW',
          },
        },
      ],
      'OutputGroups': [{
        'Name': 'File Group',
        'OutputGroupSettings': {
          'Type': 'FILE_GROUP_SETTINGS',
          'FileGroupSettings': {
            'Destination': destination, // <---- this is where the destination is set
          },
        },
        'Outputs': [{
          'NameModifier': '_1',
          'VideoDescription': {
            'ScalingBehavior': 'DEFAULT',
            'TimecodeInsertion': 'DISABLED',
            'AntiAlias': 'ENABLED',
            'Sharpness': 50,
            'AfdSignaling': 'NONE',
            'DropFrameTimecode': 'ENABLED',
            'RespondToAfd': 'NONE',
            'ColorMetadata': 'INSERT',
            'CodecSettings': {
              'Codec': 'H_264',
              'H264Settings': {
                'InterlaceMode': 'PROGRESSIVE',
                'NumberReferenceFrames': 3,
                'Syntax': 'DEFAULT',
                'Softness': 0,
                'GopClosedCadence': 1,
                'GopSize': 90,
                'Slices': 1,
                'GopBReference': 'DISABLED',
                'SlowPal': 'DISABLED',
                'SpatialAdaptiveQuantization': 'ENABLED',
                'TemporalAdaptiveQuantization': 'ENABLED',
                'FlickerAdaptiveQuantization': 'DISABLED',
                'EntropyEncoding': 'CABAC',
                'Bitrate': 5000000,
                'FramerateControl': 'SPECIFIED',
                'RateControlMode': 'CBR',
                'CodecProfile': 'MAIN',
                'Telecine': 'NONE',
                'MinIInterval': 0,
                'AdaptiveQuantization': 'HIGH',
                'CodecLevel': 'AUTO',
                'FieldEncoding': 'PAFF',
                'SceneChangeDetect': 'ENABLED',
                'QualityTuningLevel': 'SINGLE_PASS',
                'FramerateConversionAlgorithm': 'DUPLICATE_DROP',
                'UnregisteredSeiTimecode': 'DISABLED',
                'GopSizeUnits': 'FRAMES',
                'ParControl': 'SPECIFIED',
                'NumberBFramesBetweenReferenceFrames': 2,
                'RepeatPps': 'DISABLED',
                'FramerateNumerator': 30,
                'FramerateDenominator': 1,
                'ParNumerator': 1,
                'ParDenominator': 1,
              },
            },
          },
          'AudioDescriptions': [{
            'AudioTypeControl': 'FOLLOW_INPUT',
            'LanguageCodeControl': 'FOLLOW_INPUT',
            'AudioSourceName': 'Audio Selector 1',
            'CodecSettings': {
              'Codec': 'AAC',
              'AacSettings': {
                'AudioDescriptionBroadcasterMix': 'NORMAL',
                'RateControlMode': 'CBR',
                'CodecProfile': 'LC',
                'CodingMode': 'CODING_MODE_2_0',
                'RawFormat': 'NONE',
                'SampleRate': 48000,
                'Specification': 'MPEG4',
                'Bitrate': 64000,
              },
            },
          }],
          'ContainerSettings': {
            'Container': 'MP4',
            'Mp4Settings': {
              'CslgAtom': 'INCLUDE',
              'FreeSpaceBox': 'EXCLUDE',
              'MoovPlacement': 'PROGRESSIVE_DOWNLOAD',
            },
          },
        }],
      }],
    },
  };
  try {
  /*//////////////////////////////////
    ////THIS IS WHERE THE ISSUE IS////
    //////////////////////////////////*/
    // Create a promise on a MediaConvert object
    const safe_params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params));
    const template_command = new CreateJobTemplateCommand(safe_params); // destination is still defined after this line
    const data = await client.send(template_command); // destination is undefined after this line
    console.log('Success!', data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
}

async function getEndpoint() { // used in getEmcClient()
  // Create empty request parameters
  const params = {
    MaxResults: 0,
  };
  // get endpoint
  try {
    const {Endpoints} = await mediaConvert.describeEndpoints(params).promise();
    console.log(`Your MediaConvert endpoint is ${Endpoints[0].Url}`);
    return Endpoints[0].Url;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('MediaConvert Error:', err);
  }
}

async function runTranscodingJob(input_bucket, input_file, output_bucket) {
  const emc_client = await getEmcClient();
  await createMediaJobTemplate(job_template_name, output_bucket);
  const params = {
    Queue: queue_arn,
    JobTemplate: job_template_name, // TEMPLATE_NAME
    Role: role_arn, // ROLE_ARN
    Settings: {
      Inputs: [
        {
          AudioSelectors: {
            'Audio Selector 1': {
              Offset: 0,
              DefaultSelection: 'NOT_DEFAULT',
              ProgramSelection: 1,
              SelectorType: 'TRACK',
              Tracks: [1],
            },
          },
          VideoSelector: {
            ColorSpace: 'FOLLOW',
          },
          FilterEnable: 'AUTO',
          PsiControl: 'USE_PSI',
          FilterStrength: 0,
          DeblockFilter: 'DISABLED',
          DenoiseFilter: 'DISABLED',
          TimecodeSource: 'EMBEDDED',
          FileInput: `s3://${input_bucket}/${input_file}`,
        },
      ],
    },
  };
  try {
    const job_command = new CreateJobCommand(params);
    const data = await emc_client.send(job_command);
    console.log('Success! ', data);
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error', err);
  }
};

runTranscodingJob(process.env.INPUT_BUCKET, 'Videos/test.mp4', process.env.OUTPUT_BUCKET);
```

Does anyone know how I might fix this? I've read all the mediaConvert documentation I could find and spent hours debugging it, but I'm still stuck!

Comment: Have you verified `process.env.OUTPUT_BUCKET` has the value you think it does?

Comment: Yeah! I ran it through the debugger and it loaded the environment variables correctly.